# how to set the radio button's 'checked' attribute dynamically.

Tags: joomla, radio-button, components, field, checked

I've developed a Joomla 2.5 component that does ALMOST exactly what I want it to do. I have a form that contains a fieldset with 2 radio buttons (for "am" and "pm"). I have been unable to figure out how to set the appropriate button's 'checked' attribute based upon other information. It is trivial to set a default within the xml file that defines the form fields, but I don't see how I to do this dynamically.

It is possible? Have I missed something in the documentation that would explain how to do this??

Comment: Can you please tell me where you want to add those radio buttons? I mean to say in frontend form or in backend while creating menu item for our component view.

Comment: Can you add the XML for the form and the PHP code where you build the form so we've got context for our answers.

Comment: sorry - I should have mentioned that the form is used in the admin backend. I have no default radio button set in the form's xml. The component manages a set of events that can be displayed in an associated display of events. The radio buttons are for selecting whether the time of the event is am or pm.

Answer (score 1):

In case you load the form from the view: in the display() method of view.html you will be loading your form:

```
$this->form     = $this->get('Form');
```

This is invoking a model which in turns extends joomla.application.component.modelform; its getForm method loads the form:

```
$form = $this->loadForm('com_yourcomp.model', ...
```

This is what I gather from your description.  If this is not the case you might want to move the suggested code below right after you load the form: this is the complete snippet that allows you to set the value of a field:

```
/// Load the form from the model:

$this->form     = $this->get('Form');

    // Check for errors.
    if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
        throw new Exception(implode("\n", $errors));
    }

 //... some logic ...

    $this->form->setValue('businessid',null,$businessId);

    $this->form->setFieldAttribute( 'businessid', 'readonly', 'true' );
```

Comment: setFieldAttribute should be the right call, but with radio buttons, it is not at all clear (to me anyway) how I should indicate which of the buttons I want to have "checked" since they both have the same name attribute ( jform[starttime_ampm] ) - as a set of radio buttons should... and setFieldAttribute uses the 'name' to determine which field you want to set the attribute for.

I'm thinking this might be a hole in the method since radio buttons are kind of 'different' from other kinds of form fields.

I might have to give up and go to a different field type to set/get the info.

Comment: No, it's more than enough to setValue('starttime_ampm',null,'am');
null stands for the group which I guess should be empty; 'am' is the value of the radio button which stands for 'am', just put whatever value you want there.  One last consideration: have you considered writing a custom field to enter date/time so you can offset this functionality to the field, which would then hold a simple datetime and just have logic to enhance display/edit

Comment: The suggestion of @Riccardo-Zorn to use setValue is correct.
The other part of the trick seems to be that I cannot retrieve the form values at this point in the process using 
$this->form->getValue('fielnamewhatever') but I found that I COULD get them using 
$this->item->fieldnamewhatever 
... which seems a bit odd to me...shouldn't the "form->getValue" method retrieve a field value? shouldn't the item->fieldnamewhatever be a private? 

Thank you Riccardo . I'm not sure how to give credit for this response.

Comment: You're welcome, just press the "up" arrow at the top left of the answer and you should see a check sign too to accept it.